# Returning an object that implements trait from a method

Tags: rust

I have a trait defined in an external crate, and I need to return it in a method from a struct that I've defined. There's no problem to accept the trait type as an input argument, but I don't know how can I return it. The trait doesn't implement `Sized` and I can't change its implementation.

Here's a sample code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f14817b72ea24067ef61c81743ecdf6b)):

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

// this code is defined in an external crate
pub trait SomeTrait: Clone + Debug {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Implementor1(String);

impl SomeTrait for Implementor1 {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Implementor2 {
    name: String,
}

impl SomeTrait for Implementor2 {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }
}

// the code below is mine
struct ImplementorManager<T: SomeTrait> {
    implementors: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: SomeTrait> ImplementorManager<T> {
    pub fn call_get_name(implementor: T) -> String {
        implementor.get_name().to_string()
    }

    pub fn new_implementor(first: bool, name: &str) -> T {
        match first {
            true => Implementor1(name.to_string()),
            false => Implementor2 {
                name: name.to_string(),
            },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let implementor = Implementor1("first".to_string());
    println!("name: {}", ImplementorManager::call_get_name(implementor));
}
```

The error I get:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:40:21
   |
33 | impl<T: SomeTrait> ImplementorManager<T> {
   |      - this type parameter
...
38 |     pub fn new_implementor(first: bool, name: &str) -> T {
   |                                                        - expected `T` because of return type
39 |         match first {
40 |             true => Implementor1(name.to_string()),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found struct `Implementor1`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                      found struct `Implementor1`
```

If I'll comment-out the `new_implementor()` method, the `call_get_name()` method works fine accepting the trait. I've tried `Box`ing the returned object, but it is not possible without the `Sized` trait.

Is there any way I can overcome it?

### // Edit

I've kinda messed up with my explanation and example. Let me phrase it again.

I want to use `Peripheral` struct from `btleplug` crate in my struct. On Linux, this struct is public but inside a private module. Only the `Peripheral` trait is exposed in the api module.

Here's a sample code:

```rust
use btleplug::api::{BDAddr, Central, Peripheral};
use btleplug::bluez::manager::Manager;
use btleplug::Error;
use std::str::FromStr;

// cannot import the Peripheral struct as the module is private
// use btleplug::bluez::adapter::peripheral::Peripheral;

struct MyStruct<PeripheralType: Peripheral> {
    device: PeripheralType,
}

impl<PeripheralType> MyStruct<PeripheralType>
where
    PeripheralType: Peripheral,
{
    fn get_device() -> PeripheralType {
        let central = Manager::new()
            .unwrap()
            .adapters()
            .unwrap()
            .into_iter()
            .next()
            .unwrap()
            .connect()
            .unwrap();
        central
            .peripheral(BDAddr::from_str("2A:00:AA:BB:CC:DD").unwrap())
            .unwrap()
    }

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let device = Self::get_device();
        Self { device }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let _ = MyStruct::new();

    Ok(())
}
```

The error I get:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:27:9
   |
13 |   impl<PeripheralType> MyStruct<PeripheralType>
   |        -------------- this type parameter
...
17 |       fn get_device() -> PeripheralType {
   |                          -------------- expected `PeripheralType` because of return type
...
27 | /         central
28 | |             .peripheral(BDAddr::from_str("2A:00:AA:BB:CC:DD").unwrap())
29 | |             .unwrap()
   | |_____________________^ expected type parameter `PeripheralType`, found struct `btleplug::bluez::adapter::peripheral::Peripheral`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `PeripheralType`
                      found struct `btleplug::bluez::adapter::peripheral::Peripheral`
```

It somehow seems to [work internally](https://github.com/deviceplug/btleplug/blob/master/src/api/adapter_manager.rs#L20), but I don't understand why it doesn't work in my example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```rust
impl<PeripheralType> MyStruct<PeripheralType>
where
    PeripheralType: Peripheral,
{
    fn get_device() -> PeripheralType {
        ...
        central
            .peripheral(BDAddr::from_str("2A:00:AA:BB:CC:DD").unwrap())
            .unwrap()
    }
```

you are getting the type dependencies backwards: you are assuming an arbitrary type for `PeripheralType` (that's what `impl<PeripheralType>` means) and then trying to use a value of a specific but unnameable type for it.

(Side note: unnameable types also appear when using *closures* in Rust — each closure definition has a unique unnameable type — so this is not an unusual problem.)

Instead, what you need to do to make this work is *first* get the value and *then* make the struct for it. First, here's a definition of `get_device` that should work, because `impl Peripheral` exactly describes the situation of "I have a trait implementation but I'm not saying which one":

```rust
// This should NOT be in an `impl<PeripheralType>` block.

fn get_device() -> impl Peripheral {
    let central = Manager::new()
        .unwrap()
        .adapters()
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .connect()
        .unwrap();
    central
        .peripheral(BDAddr::from_str("2A:00:AA:BB:CC:DD").unwrap())
        .unwrap()
}
```

Then using this, you can **construct your struct using this return value**.

```rust
fn main() {
    let device = get_device();
    let my_struct = MyStruct { device };
    my.do_something();
}
```

There's a catch to this, however: you can't ever write down the type of `my_struct` because it contains an unnameable parameter. If you need to do that, then I think you will have to instead go with dynamic dispatch:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    device: Box<dyn Peripheral>,
}
```

With this type, there is no type parameter to give you trouble. (You'll need to write `Box::new(central...unwrap())` to initialize the struct field.) The catch is that passing `device` *to* something that expects a certain peripheral type won't work.

> It somehow seems to [work internally](https://github.com/deviceplug/btleplug/blob/master/src/api/adapter_manager.rs#L20), but I don't understand why it doesn't work in my example...

That code works because it is fully generic; it doesn't have a `get_device` that's trying to make the peripheral type more specific than "whatever my type parameter is".

---

#### Old answer text for the first attempt at the question

**This function cannot work, regardless of how you try to implement it:**

```
impl<T: SomeTrait> ImplementorManager<T> {
    ...
    pub fn new_implementor(first: bool, name: &str) -> T {
        match first {
            true => Implementor1(...),
            false => Implementor2 {...},
        }
    }
}
```

When you write `-> T` inside `impl<T: SomeTrait>` you are saying *this method will always return `T` for all `T`s that implement `SomeTrait`.*  But that's not what you're doing; you're returning two different specific types which are *not* guaranteed to be equal to `T`.

The fundamental problem here is that you're currently trying to choose a type parameter (`T`) based on a value (`first`), which is not possible. The solution is to *use* the static type information, which you can do by writing your own trait and implementations:

```
trait SomeTraitFactory: SomeTrait {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self;
}

impl SomeTraitFactory for Implementor1 {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
        Implementor1(name.to_string())
    }
}

impl SomeTraitFactory for Implementor2 {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
        Implementor2 {
            name: name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have this factory, you can then have `ImplementorManager` use it wherever it wants:

```
impl<T: SomeTraitFactory> ImplementorManager<T> {
    ...

    pub fn new_implementor(name: &str) -> T {
        <T as SomeTraitFactory>::new(name)
    }
}
```

Note that the `bool` parameter is gone, because the type of `ImplementorManager` you're using entirely determines which implementor is constructed. It's a little annoying to call `new_implementor`, however, because you need to write out the type parameter:

```
<ImplementorManager<Implementor2>>::new_implementor("second")
```

This problem goes away when you start actually using an `ImplementorManager` *value,* in methods with `self`, because the type can be carried along by using `Self`:

```
impl<T: SomeTraitFactory> ImplementorManager<T> {
    ...

    pub fn push_implementor(&mut self, name: &str) {
        self.implementors.push(Self::new_implementor(name));
    }
}
```

---

On the other hand, if you actually want to have `Implementor1` and `Implementor2` in the same `ImplementorManager`, then all the `<T>`s are unwanted and you need to use the `Box<dyn Trait>` approach instead. That won't work directly because `SomeTrait: Clone` and `Clone` is not object-safe, but you can add a wrapper trait which forwards to `SomeTrait` but hides the `Clone` part:

```
trait SomeTraitWrapper: Debug {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
}
impl<T: SomeTrait> SomeTraitWrapper for T {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        SomeTrait::get_name(self)
    }
}
```

Then `ImplementorManager` is a straightforward use of `dyn`:

```
struct ImplementorManager {
    implementors: Vec<Box<dyn SomeTraitWrapper>>,
}

impl ImplementorManager {
    pub fn call_get_name(implementor: Box<dyn SomeTraitWrapper>) -> String {
        implementor.get_name().to_string()
    }
    
    pub fn new_implementor(first: bool, name: &str) -> Box<dyn SomeTraitWrapper> {
        match first {
            true => Box::new(Implementor1(name.to_string())),
            false => Box::new(Implementor2 {
                name: name.to_string(),
            }),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I've messed up my example and explanation. I've edited my question to reflect it better. Basically, I want to use traits as interfaces known from other languages, as I cannot import the `Implementor` class directly.

Comment: @Djent I don't understand the description you gave. It's not **possible** for a crate to have a public function `get_implementor() -> Implementor` if `Implementor` is a private type — the compiler will reject that. We need to see the actual situation or a more accurate representation of it.

Comment: Right, the crate is quite tricky as it differs on Windows and Linux. I need to dig deeper into it and update the question again.

Comment: I've updated the example with the real-life crate. Basically, the struct is public but is defined within a private module. If I try to import this struct, I'll get the error that the `peripheral` module is private.

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to getting it. Does that mean that I can't create a new instance in `MyStruct::new()` and I always need some helper function that is not member of `MyStruct` that will create a new instance?

Comment: @Djent If you do that, you have to not use the `Self` type (because `Self` has the wrong type parameter). You can write `fn new() -> MyStruct<impl Peripheral> {...}` or `fn new<P: Peripheral>(device: P) -> MyStruct<P> {...}`; but the catch is that you'll have to provide a dummy type parameter to be able to _call_ it, like `<MyStruct<SomethingKnownToImplementPeripheral>>::new()`. You probably don't want that.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I just wonder, is there any workaround for not having to import Peripheral trait in project that will use my library? I've noticed `pub type MyStructType = MyStruct<impl Peripheral>;`, but it works only in nightly. Is there any equivalent in stable?

Comment: @Djent I don't know and I have no further ideas.

Answer (score 0):

By using making `new_implementor` a trait that is implemented by each object:

```
fn new_implementor<U: SomeTrait>(x: U) -> U
where
    U: DoSomething,
{
    x.do_something()
}
```

Everything will look like the following:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub trait SomeTrait: Clone + Debug {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Implementor1(String);

impl Implementor1 {
    fn new(a: &str) -> Implementor1 {
        Self(a.to_string())
    }
}

impl SomeTrait for Implementor1 {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Implementor2 {
    name: String,
}

impl SomeTrait for Implementor2 {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }
}

trait DoSomething {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Self
    where
        Self: SomeTrait;
    // T: SomeTrait;
}

impl DoSomething for Implementor1 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Implementor1 {
        Implementor1::new(&self.0)
    }
}

impl DoSomething for Implementor2 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Implementor2 {
        Self {
            name: self.name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

// the code below is mine
struct ImplementorManager<T: SomeTrait> {
    implementors: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: SomeTrait> ImplementorManager<T> {
    pub fn call_get_name(implementor: T) -> String {
        implementor.get_name().to_string()
    }

    fn new_implementor<U: SomeTrait>(x: U) -> U
    where
        U: DoSomething,
    {
        x.do_something()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let implementor2 = Implementor2 {
        name: "test".to_string(),
    };
    let implementor1 = Implementor1("test".to_string());
    println!(
        "name: {:?}",
        ImplementorManager::<Implementor2>::new_implementor(implementor2)
    );
    println!(
        "name: {:?}",
        ImplementorManager::<Implementor1>::new_implementor(implementor1)
    );
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a4a5866a214e0ed02ce6754eadaeb45)

Comment: But I already have the `T: SomeTrait`. In your example, you're just passing the object through. I want to create a new instance of it and return. Notice, that I don't have the argument with the same type as the output in the `new_implementor` method.

Comment: You can change the argument easily. Please see this example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8349afc11064831b8ec61b2e619d26c. There are two generics to make things clear. But you can use only one

Comment: I think I've messed up my example and explanation. I've edited my question to reflect it better. Basically, I want to use traits as interfaces known from other languages, as I cannot import the `Implementor` class directly.